# Is it possible to create a module or parent class that makes all methods class methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Class methods are normally defined with `self.foo` or `class << self`.

Is it possible to make all methods class methods by using a module or parent class?

For example:

```
class Foo
  include ClassMethods

  def bar
```

or

```
class Foo < ClassMethods
  def bar
```

And use

```
Foo.bar
```

What would ClassMethods be?

Answer (score 2):

Converting your `Class` to a `Module` and using `extend self` should do what you want. For every method in the Module it creates a class method.

So your example could be written as:

```
module Foo
  extend self

  def bar
```

---

Another way would be to use [Module#refine](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-refine), which can turn a class into a module. So you could make a module of your class and then extend your class with that created module.

Comment: According to the Ruby Style Guide (not a definitive guide, just community-created suggested guidelines), you should favor `module_function` over `extend self`: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#module-function

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to have `Foo` be a module instead of a class, use `module_function`.

```
module Foo
  module_function

  def bar
```

Then this will work:

```
Foo.bar
```